# Why does extJS give me "Ext.Panel is not a constructor" error in Firebug?

Tags: extjs

I am working through [this extJS tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Playing_With_Ext_The_Easy_Way) where you type in code into Firebug, press CTRL-Enter and it renders it for you, it worked for the simple example but then I got this error:

### Instructions:

[image]

### What happens:

[image]

**What else do I need to do to get this example to work as it states it will in the demo?**

Comment: is this question resolved? Did my answer make sense?

Comment: yes, I realized that I was not in the right tab, going into the right tab (with the js files loaded) solved the problem, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have `ext-all.js` (and maybe `ext-base.js`?) loaded in the page you're testing for this to work. The example isn't working properly for you because the Panel file cannot be located. It doesn't exist because you haven't added it.

Test the Ext.Panel code in firebug at the API site: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/

You'll see that the desired behavior occurs because the page has all of the proper JS files loaded. Any time you see the message "... is not a constructor" should be an indication that the JS file containing the object has not been loaded into the page.

Comment: I would recommend `ext-all-debug.js` so that errors will make more sense.

Comment: @bmoeskau, that's a good point. ext-all.js would only be a quick fix for this issue. @Edward, if any other issues arise use ext-all-debug.js like bmoeskau recommends.